# Using differentials (not limits!) to find the derivative of sqrt(x)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, differential

So I understand how to find the derivative of $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ using the power rule.

I also know how to find it using the limit. $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}}{h}$

You could replace h and f' in that formula with dx and df/dx to find a formula like this:

$\frac{df}{dx} = \lim_{dx \to 0} \frac{(x+dx)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}}{dx}$

That kind of looks like what I want, but eventually I'm trying to get to this formula I've seen around

$df = (x+dx)^{1/2} - x^{1/2}$

Then I want to use that to get to df = something*dx

I can't figure out how to isolate the dx, which sucks.

An example of the logic I want is in the following proof about $f=x^2$

$df = (x+dx)^{2}-x^2$

$df = x^2+2x*dx+(dx)^2-x^2$

$df = 2x*dx+(dx)^2$

Then you can ignore an infinitesimal df times itself as inconsequential.

So $df = 2x*dx$

Does anyone even know what I mean when I'm asking this question? I am confused myself, but I want to understand the df = something * dx way of doing things

Think it will be useful for linear algebra when x is a matrix

Comment: In your example of the squaring function, you are essentially doing the same manipulations as you would in the limit definition, just with differential notation. Do you know how to compute the derivative of the square root function using the limit definition? Hint: multiply and divide by the conjugate.

Comment: Hint: use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ as follows: $$
\frac{{\sqrt {x + dx}  - \sqrt x }}{{dx}} = \frac{{\sqrt {x + dx}  - \sqrt x }}{{dx}}\frac{{\sqrt {x + dx}  + \sqrt x }}{{\sqrt {x + dx}  + \sqrt x }} = \frac{{dx}}{{dx(\sqrt {x + dx}  + \sqrt x )}} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {x + dx}  + \sqrt x }}.
$$

Comment: This makes sense so far, but now dx is awkwardly on the bottom and we still want something like df = something * dx right? 

Is there some really obvious way to get dx out of there? Is there a type of math class online I should look into to solve problems like this?

Comment: @username_entity That dx term on the bottom vanishes in the limit; at the end of the day, you are computing a limit by finding the derivative

Comment: Squaring the function before differentiating yields
$$\eqalign{
x &= f^2 \\
dx &= 2f\;df \\
df &= \left(\frac{\tt1}{2f}\right)dx \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $df=(x+dx)^{1/2}−x^{1/2} \implies df=x^{1/2}(1+\frac{dx}{x})^{1/2}−x^{1/2} \implies df=x^{1/2}(1+\frac{dx}{2x})−x^{1/2}$$\implies df=\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}} $
(Using the approximation $(1+x)^n=1+nx$ when $x$ is very small compared to $1$.)

Comment: The approximation you are using is basically coming from the derivative, but that is what we are after.

Comment: but $(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!} x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} x^3 $ .......
and but x->0 thus $x^2$ and $x^3$ are negligible @Gary

Comment: @Gary I was approximating with the help of binomial expansion as parth has conveyed.

Comment: @parthsachdeva How do you prove the binomial series for $n=1/2$ without using the derivative of $(1+x)^{1/2}$? My point is that you are using something which is stronger than what you actually want to prove.